# Make onDataChange work only when app is in the foreground (open and visible)?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I make `onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)` work only when my app is in the foreground? I don't want it to detect any changes when my app is in the background!

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/saving-data/fireblog/posts");

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { //only when app is in the foreground!
        System.out.println("change");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to remove the listener according to activity life-cycle like this:

```
databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

If you have added the listener in `onCreate` you have to remove it in `onDestroy`. If you have added the listener in `onStart` you have to remove it in `onStop`. If you have added the listener in `onResume` you have to remove it in `onPause`.

Your class should look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference ref;
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("myproj").child("data");
        valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //get data
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
        if(valueEventListener != null) {
            databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer.

Comment: I have added `databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);` but Android Studio highlights `databaseReference` in red bevause it can't find it. I declared `databaseReference` in `onCreate`

Comment: It highlights in red because the name of your `DatabaseReferenc` object is other. I wrote as an example, if you were using this line of code: `DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();` If the name of the variable si `ref` or `yourRef` or any other name, just use it in stead of `databaseReference`.

Comment: can you give a simple example of a real implementation please? upvoted

Comment: here's my real code; `final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://myproj/data");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

Comment: I want to do ref.removeEventListener(valueEventListener); from onDestroy. How?

Comment: This does not work for me. Are you sure you didn't forget something?

Answer (score 3):

The answers from Alex and Saurabh show how to remove the listener while your app is backgrounded.

An alternative is to explicitly tell Firebase to stop synchronizing. In the `onPause` of your activity call [`goOffline()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#goOffline()). Then in the `onResume` method call [`goOnline()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#goOnline()).

Comment: Why doesn't the following work? `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://‌​‌​myproj-21a87.fireb‌​as‌​eio.com/data").g‌​oOnl‌​ine();` Thanks for your efficient answer!

Comment: Because you need to call `goOnline()` and `goOffline()` on a `FirebaseDatabase` object: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline()`.

Comment: How can I "go offline" on a specific part of my database though? That's what I want to do.

Comment: Your question was explicitly to not detect any changes while the app is in the background. Calling `goOffline()` is a way to accomplish that. If you only want certain locations to stop receiving updates, you'll have to remove the listeners from those locations as Alex and Saurabh have shown/said.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work when visible :
In your on Resume :-

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
        System.out.println("change");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
    });
    }
```

In your on Destroy set it to null:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ref.addValueEventListener(null);
}
```

Comment: Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: @Saurabh: you probably want to actually **remove** the listener in `onDestroy()`.